# Making a master CMakeLists.txt

Tags: catkin-make, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a huge 107 package ROS project, and due to various issues regarding multi-platform and versions and build machine configurations, we have lots of OpenCV version issues. Futhermore, there are lots of boilerplate code, such as setting up CUDA, that get repeated in many files.

So, is there an easy way to place a `CMakeLists.txt` in, say, the root directory and have it automatically included?

Note, [this solution from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17229324/1270789) could work, but can I avoid having to edit 107 `CMakeLists.txt`s, including making sure I get the right number of `../`s, since we have a multi-level build tree?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275318/making-a-master-cmakelists.txt/) by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2017-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are probably already aware, but anything you do will most likely make your packages harder to reuse outside your project as you are adding a dependency on an external file that is then hard-/en-coding certain assumptions of your build environment.

Having said that, two options I can come up with:

1. use the Catkin `CFG_EXTRAS` infrastructure. From [catkin documentation - package format 2 - CMake files](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/installing_cmake.html):

   > Sometimes your package needs to install CMake files for use by other packages. For that to work, your `catkin_package()` command must include a `CFG_EXTRAS` parameter, where you list the CMake files you want to export:

   > ```
   > catkin_package(CFG_EXTRAS your_macros.cmake your_modules.cmake)
   > ```

   > When another package uses `find_package()` on this package, the listed CMake files are automatically included.

I don't know whether it is possible in your case, but you could see whether placing such a file in a low-level dependency that all / a large part of your packages already `find_package(..)` would work. The `CFG_EXTRAS` CMake file can do just about anything a regular CMake file does, but you can't really control ordering of inclusion this way, which may be problematic.

```
For more info, see also the [catkin extracted API documentation - catkin_package(..)](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html#catkin-package).
```

1. **not recommended** (at all): `unlink` the `catkins_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt` that is there (as it's really a symlink), then copy the one from `/opt/ros/$rosdistro/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake` to `catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt`. Now this is a regular file and you could edit it (do *not* edit the file in `/opt/ros`). This is the top-level file responsible for organising the build of the entire workspace (at least with `catkin_make`), so should perhaps allow you to do some early setup/configuration work.

   Note: this file is typically managed by Catkin itself, so there will probably be situations where you will lose your changes (because Catkin overwrites it for some reason). I'm not sure how often that would be though.

And again: relying on a single, central `CMakeLists.txt` will significantly increase coupling between your packages (to the point where they can't be built without the shared file anymore). That would not seem to align well with the distributed (federated) development style that ROS promotes, but that may be acceptable in your situation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1